# teamcity agent unable to build .Net 5

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I am trying to setup a build pipeline in teamcity. My pipeline is failing at `.Net build` Looks like teamcity is trying to build it with .Net core 3.1 and my solution is of .Net 5

Complete error message: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks`

How do I tell teamcity build agent to use a specific .Net version to build my application?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the .NET 5.0 SDK is not installed on the Build Agent.

I have put the 5.0 SDK on my agents and it just seems to use them with no other changes.